# How can I read the last n columns of a CSV with bad lines with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, missing-data

I've encountered an issue while attempting to read a CSV file with pandas. The CSV structure is as follows:

```
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5
a1, a2, a3, a4, a5
b1, b2, b3, b4, b5
c1, c3, c4, c5
d1, d2, d3, d4, d5
```

Some rows contain missing values, and I specifically want to extract only the last `n` cells of each row, as these are guaranteed to exist. In the given example, where `n=3`, the desired DataFrame should look like this:

```
    Col3 Col4 Col5
0   a3   a4   a5
1   b3   b4   b5
2   c3   c4   c5
3   d3   d4   d5
```

I attempted to use usecols=[2, 3, 4], but it resulted in N/A values:

```
   Col3  Col4  Col5
0    a3    a4    a5
1    b3    b4    b5
2    c4    c5   NaN
3    d3    d4    d5
```

Any guidance on how to achieve the desired result would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: computer is not so clever to know that you are missing `c2` in row. It may need to use standard `open()`, `read()` to resolve it. Eventually you may have to iterate rows in `DataFrame` and moves cells to right on your own.

Comment: What happens if, instead, you are missing `c2` and `c5`? How do you know what you are missing?

Comment: what's the expected result for this row: `c1, , c3, , c5` with `n=3` ?

Comment: @DiegoH, your I/O don't match! In your expected output, where do `Col5` come from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fun, you can try a [*regex*](https://regex101.com/r/AEmVeM/1) separator :

```
N = 3 # last N columns

pat = r".+?{}?$".format("([^,]+),"*N)

df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=pat, engine="python").dropna(how="all", axis=1)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   Col2  Col3  Col4
0    a3    a4    a5
1    b3    b4    b5
2    c3    c4    c5
3    d3    d4    d5
```

Comment: Love the trick, works perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to handle this directly at the level of [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). An option might be to load all the data, then to realign it:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data)

mask = df.notna().loc[:, ::-1].cummax(axis=1).loc[:, ::-1]

out = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df))[:,None],
                                 np.argsort(mask)],
                   index=df.index, columns=df.columns
                  )
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
a1   a2    a3    a4    a5
b1   b2    b3    b4    b5
c1  NaN    c3    c4    c5
d1   d2    d3    d4    d5
```

You can then select only the desired columns

If you only want to handle the last `n` columns:

```
last_col = 3

mask = df.notna().iloc[:, :-last_col-1:-1].cummax(axis=1).iloc[:, ::-1]

out = df.copy()
out.iloc[:, -last_col:] = (df
                     .iloc[:, -last_col:]
                     .to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df))[:,None],
                                 np.argsort(mask)])
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
a1   a2    a3    a4    a5
b1   b2    b3    b4    b5
c1   c3   NaN    c4    c5
d1   d2    d3    d4    d5
```

Answer (score 1):

If pandas is not a requirement, I think I would use the CSV package and a default reader to pick out the last three columns of each row:

Something like:

```py
import io
import csv

data = """
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5
b1,b2,b3,b4,b5
c1,c3,c4,c5
d1,d2,d3,d4,d5
""".strip()

with io.StringIO(data) as file_in:
    reader = csv.reader(file_in)
    headers = next(reader)  # not sure if you want/nead the header
    rows = [row[-3:] for row in reader] # the last three columns
```

Now you can do what you like with `rows`

```py
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

will give you:

```
['a3', 'a4', 'a5']
['b3', 'b4', 'b5']
['c3', 'c4', 'c5']
['d3', 'd4', 'd5']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract values of last cell of each row than you can use the following code to get last cell of each row.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv_data = """
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
a1, a2, a3, a4, a5
b1, b2, b3, b4, b5
c1, c3, c4, c5
d1, d2, d3, d4, d5
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data))

last_values = df.apply(lambda row: row.dropna().iloc[-1] if not row.dropna().empty else pd.NA, axis=1)

for _, value in zip(last_values.index, last_values):
    print(value)
```

"df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data))"
This line uses the pd.read_csv function to read the CSV data into a Pandas DataFrame (df). The StringIO(csv_data) is used to convert the string csv_data into a file-like object that pd.read_csv can read.

"last_values = df.apply(lambda row: row.dropna().iloc[-1] if not row.dropna().empty else pd.NA, axis=1)"
Here, a new Series called last_values is created by applying a lambda function to each row of the DataFrame (df). The lambda function checks if the row has any non-null values using row.dropna(). If it's not empty, it extracts the last non-null value using iloc[-1]. If the row is empty, it assigns pd.NA (Pandas' representation of a missing value).

"
for _, value in zip(last_values.index, last_values):
print(value)
"
Finally, a loop iterates over the index and values of the last_values Series, and it prints each value. This loop essentially prints the last non-null value in each row of the original DataFrame.